# deploy dotnet core cli mvc application to azure webservice

Tags: web-services, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I want to deploy my .NET Core MVC application in an azure WebService. I have built the app locally with

```
dotnet publish
```

and moved the output code with the Kudu service in my wwwroot directory but the wabapp just gives me the errorpage:

```
deploy .NET Core CLI MVC application to azure web service
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? If so, you should follow this guide: [Publish an ASP.NET Core web app to Azure App Service using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vs)

Comment: where exactly do you see this error message "deploy dotnet core cli mvc application to azure webservice"?

Comment: no im using dotnet core cli and visualstudio code

Comment: did you see a "web.config" file under wwwroot directory after you copy over the bits?

Comment: no there is not a "web.config" file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with a sample project:

```
D:\dotnetDummy>dotnet publish
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.3.409.57025 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  dotnetDummy -> D:\dotnetDummy\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\dotnetDummy.dll
  dotnetDummy -> D:\dotnetDummy\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\publish\  <-- output directory
```

after publishing locally, you want to move all files under output directory to wwwroot folder of your azure webapp, in this case your `D:\home\site\wwwroot` on Kudu site should look the same as `D:\dotnetDummy\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\publish`

```
D:\dotnetDummy\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\publish>dir /B  
dotnetDummy.deps.json
dotnetDummy.dll
dotnetDummy.pdb
dotnetDummy.PrecompiledViews.dll
dotnetDummy.PrecompiledViews.pdb
dotnetDummy.runtimeconfig.json
web.config   <-- output of dotnet publish
```

if you don't see `web.config` under wwwroot, I would guess there's a mistake during the move